No color format in Google Colab
There is a .ipynb file in Google Colab with no color formatting (I also can't for example use Ctrl+Shift+7 to comment a line). However, in other documents of the same extension, I can. It's no big deal since the first document works perfectly, but I would like to see what's the deal.
